# How to install `virtualenvwrapper` on Mac (2021)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm struggling pretty hard to find a tutorial that's still relevant.  Is `virtualenvwrapper` no longer relevant on Mac (OS 11.4) as of 2021?

I get this on opening my `zsh`:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

```
➜  ~ echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
/usr/bin/python3
➜  ~ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
➜  ~ which virtualenvwrapper.sh
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

where my `~/.zshrc` contains:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

# For virtualenvwrapper
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
export WORKON_HOME=${HOME}/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
#export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=${HOME}/.local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source $(which virtualenvwrapper.sh)
```

I no longer have python3 installed from the Mac installer downloaded from https://www.python.org/downloads/.

I appear to have no less than three installations of python3:

```
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
```

and my latest attempt at installing python3 with `brew` fails at `pygobject`:

```
➜  ~ brew reinstall pygobject
==> Downloading https://download.gnome.org/sources/pygobject/2.28/pygobject-2.28.7.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/stellios/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/229c52d9a07d25ee8cea203c1a0a6d567c422a034c9ff0a686a9f84e0fa0fd68--pygobject-2.28.7.tar.xz
==> Reinstalling pygobject 
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  FormulaUnavailableError: No available formula with the name "/usr/local/opt/pygobject/.brew/pygobject.rb".
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still at a loss as why all the python3 version and places, but standardizing on `/usr/loca/bin` seems to resolve my issues.

```
# For virtualenvwrapper
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH                                            
export WORKON_HOME=${HOME}/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```